# How to count integers within a tuple?

Tags: python

So I have a list of tuples which looks like:

```
[(1, 60),
 (1, 93),
 (1, 104),
 (1, 145),
 (1, 159),
 (4, 20),
 (4, 30),
 (4, 103),
 (8, 8),
 (9, 35),
 (9, 172),
 (9, 191),
 (10, 33),
 (10, 164),
 (10, 185)]
```

However, the numbers on the left side of the tuple should all be unique. So I would like to have something like this:

```
[(1, 60),
 (4, 20),
 (8, 8),
 (9, 35),
 (10, 33)]
```

I tried to make some unique functions in order to filter them out. But for example the count function does not work for integers.

Comment: What do these number represent?

Comment: Can you drop some of the example code you've written? It might help people understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What does counting have to do with this?  What you need to determine is if the first element in the tuple has been seen before - membership in a set would be a reasonable way of determining that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test = [(1, 60),
 (1, 93),
 (1, 104),
 (1, 145),
 (1, 159),
 (4, 20),
 (4, 30),
 (4, 103),
 (8, 8),
 (9, 35),
 (9, 172),
 (9, 191),
 (10, 33),
 (10, 164),
 (10, 185)]
seen = set()
print([x for x in test if x[0] not in seen and not seen.add(x[0])])
>>>
[(1, 60), (4, 20), (8, 8), (9, 35), (10, 33)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Each tuple in your list has two elements. Let's call the first one a "key".

We're going to create an empty list to fill with the tuples we want.
Let's also create a set (`already_added`) containing the keys we have already added. For each tuple, we need to check if the "key" exists in `already_added`, and only add it to our result if it doesn't.

```
lst = [(1, 60),
 (1, 93),
 (1, 104),
 (1, 145),
 (1, 159),
 (4, 20),
 (4, 30),
 (4, 103),
 (8, 8),
 (9, 35),
 (9, 172),
 (9, 191),
 (10, 33),
 (10, 164),
 (10, 185)]

result = []
already_added = set()

for item in lst:
    if item[0] not in already_added:
        result.append(item)
        already_added.add(item[0])
```

This gives us the following `result`:

```
[(1, 60), (4, 20), (8, 8), (9, 35), (10, 33)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple solution:

```
x=[(1, 60),
 (1, 93),
 (1, 104),
 (1, 145),
 (1, 159),
 (4, 20),
 (4, 30),
 (4, 103),
 (8, 8),
 (9, 35),
 (9, 172),
 (9, 191),
 (10, 33),
 (10, 164),
 (10, 185)]
x.reverse()
l={i:(i,j) for i,j in x}
filter_list = list(l.values())
filter_list.reverse()
```

Since you care about the first occurrence, we revert the list to add the elements to a dictionary, since we use the first integer as a key, the elements will be overwritten and the last one to appear will be your first occurrence, then we keep the values and revert the list again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to with key-value pairs the unique identifier of the tuple and the tuple itself as the value.

```
lst = # from above

# if ordering is important
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda p: (p[0], -p[1]))

# grant unicity in 1st entry (take latest entry for each repeated key)
lst = {x: (x, y) for x, y in lst}

res = list(lst.values())
```